# While we are create list and list columns using "pnp/sp". Why some of the columns are not created in one go?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

While we are create list and list columns using [pnp/sp](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/fields/). Why some of the columns are not created in one go? We need to run again then it will created. Please help me to resolve this issue.

I have used SPFx solution with react and "pnp/sp". Please refer below configuration for the same.

- node 14.15.4
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.14.0
- gulp@4.0.2
- npm@6.14.10
- yo@4.3.0
- @pnp/sp@2.11.0

Please refer below code snippet for the same.

```js
import { sp } from '@pnp/sp';
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/fields";
import "@pnp/sp/views";
import { UrlFieldFormatType } from "@pnp/sp/fields";

export const trainingsList = async () => {
    try {
        const listEnsureResult = await sp.web.lists.ensure("Trainings", "Trainings", 100, false, { Hidden: false });
        if (listEnsureResult.created) {
            return listEnsureResult;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in Trainings List", error);
    }
}

export const trainingsFields = async () => {
    const courseList = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Course")();
    try {
        await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.select("*").get().then(async (res) => {
            let listData = [];
            res.forEach(ele => {
                listData.push(ele.InternalName);
            });

            if (listData.indexOf("VideoUrl") == -1) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addUrl("VideoUrl", UrlFieldFormatType.Hyperlink).then(() => {
                        sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("VideoUrl");
                    })
                }, 5000);
            }

            if (listData.indexOf("Walkthrough") == -1) {
                sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addMultilineText("Walkthrough").then(() => {
                    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("Walkthrough");
                });
            }

            if (listData.indexOf("Status") == -1) {
                sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addBoolean("Status").then(() => {
                    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("Status");
                });
            }

            if (listData.indexOf("TrainingDuration") == -1) {
                sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addNumber("TrainingDuration").then(() => {
                    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("TrainingDuration");
                });
            }

            if (listData.indexOf("Course") == -1) {
                sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addLookup("Course", courseList.Id, "Title").then(() => {
                    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("Course");
                });
            }

            await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.select("*").get().then(async (resListData) => {
                let listColumnData = [];
                resListData.forEach(ele => {
                    listColumnData.push(ele.InternalName);
                });
                console.log("listColumnData...", listColumnData);

                if (listColumnData.indexOf("VideoUrl") != -1 && listColumnData.indexOf("Walkthrough") != -1 && listColumnData.indexOf("Status") != -1 && listColumnData.indexOf("TrainingDuration") != -1 && listColumnData.indexOf("Course") != -1) {
                    console.log("Inside IF.....");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Inside ELSE.....");
                    await trainingsFields();
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error in trainings fields creation", err);
            });
            console.log("Trainings fields created successfully!");
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error in Trainings fields", err);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in Trainings fields", error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `await` with `add` functions, otherwise your function may terminate before all fields are created. In general, I would avoid mixing `await` with `.then` for simplicity. Consider something like:

```js
if (listData.indexOf("Walkthrough") == -1) {
 await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addMultilineText("Walkthrough");
 await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("Walkthrough");
}

if (listData.indexOf("Status") == -1) {
 await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").fields.addBoolean("Status");
 await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Trainings").defaultView.fields.add("Status");
}
```

Normally, you should get a linter (or compiler) error or warning when you try to call an asynchronous function without waiting for it to terminate in some way (i.e. without `await` or `.then` or `.catch`), i.e. "shooting in the air", but this may depend on the linter settings, as far as I remember.

TLDR: replace all `foo().then(result => ..)` with `const result = await foo()` and you should be fine.

Another thing, there may be a much more efficient way to create fields not just in "one go" but in "one call", if you used batches, for example.